# Adding ST_GEOMETRY column to existing table that already has X Y columns?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog, st-geometry

- I have created and Oracle 11g geospatial geodatabase and have create an arcsde connection.
- I have been connected using arcmap, as a simple user (not sde or schema-user), who has all the proper rights to edit tables etc..
- I use arcgis for desktop 10.2.
- In my geodatabase I have created all my business tables needed for my applications.
  In this geodatabase there is on table tha contains X Y points.
- I suppose that I need to add an st_geomery column so as to enable arcgis realise that it contains geometries (points), have indexing etc.

---

1. One option is to alter the table via an oracle query and add an st_geometry column.
   In this case I cannot see the table in the listed tables in arcmap. I dont know **why**.
2. I suppose that a second option could be to edit this table through arcmap and add a st_geometry column of points. But I cannot find any option in arcmap to do this.

When I double click on my table i can see these options (missing st_geometry option)

[image]

**Any help on these two options?**

Comment: Tables are altered with DDL, not queries (DML). Was the table registered with the geodatabase prior to altering the table?

Comment: Yes Vince. It has been registered.

Comment: Also I want to mention that as I have noticed . When I register a table to a geodatabase, the changes (ex add a new column) I make from inside the Oracle Sql Developer client are not visible in arcmap. even after refreshing my sde connection. I tried the same with a not registered table an the changes are visible.

Comment: You should not issue DDL against tables after they have been registered with the geodatabase, since this corrupts the registration.

Comment: It looks like you just want the second option offered in this link http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00s50000001z000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the st_geometry had not been correctly installed at the time I ran the Create Enterprise Geodatabase Tool.

I had to fix the exproc file  so as during the creation of the geodatabase, the st_geometry to be properly installed.

The absence of St_geometry made my Arcgis recognise the tables containing st_geometry as invalid.